# Why configure with Sagas()?

Tags: nservicebus

Why is it necessary to configure with Sagas()? I ask because I had been running a saga with raven persistence for the last few months before I noticed the Sagas() is not in the configure.with, in fact I realized I was missing a bit of the RavenPersistence stuff as well. Yet, as far as I know Sagas have been working 98% of the time and persisting to Raven. So I wonder what the Sagas() configuration does differently than not configuring it.

The reason I say 98% of the time is I do notice random messages falling out of a method and not sending the next message it is designated to send in the Saga. I am curious if not having the proper configuration is the cause of this.

```
        _logger.InfoFormat("1.1 - Preparing Saga for; File: {0}", message.FileNumber);

        //Creates Saga information 
        SetupSaga(uploads,
                  message.Documents,
                  message.ProcedureID.GetValueOrDefault(0),
                  file.Client.Id,
                  message.FileNumber,
                  message.Stage,
                  user);

        _logger.InfoFormat("1.2 - Upload Saga Unique ID; File: {0}, UniqueID: {1}", message.FileNumber, Data.UniqueID);

        Bus.SendLocal(new GetLoanInformation {
            UniqueID = Data.UniqueID
        });
```

Comment: Are you hosting in the NServiceBus.Host.exe process or self-hosting?

Comment: It's deployed to an application server as the Host process.

Comment: Post edit, this really becomes a different question, and I'm not sure there's enough information available to answer it. I'd encourage you to create a new question with more detail (particularly, what does the SetupSaga method do?) and then link this question to that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NServiceBus Host does a lot of configuration automatically based on roles and profiles. Both the Sagas configuration and the Raven persistence are handled for you automatically. You would only need to do this manually if you were going to run a Saga when self-hosting, which would be somewhat rare.

For a better idea of what happens as a result of all the different roles and profiles, check out [All About NServiceBus Host Profiles and Roles](http://www.make-awesome.com/2013/02/all-about-nservicebus-host-profiles-and-roles/). (Disclaimer: This is my blog post.)

The problem you're mentioning is due to something else, but a lot more information would be required to diagnose it.

Comment: I added the code in question to my original question. Thank you for this blog, this will certainly come in handy in understanding profiles and roles. As for the code I provided, that is the piece in which it is falling out. The method does some preliminary work, sets up the saga, then sends a message to the next piece in line. Roughly 2% of the time, it is never sending the next message.

Comment: I have checked the Transactional dead-letter queue and am not seeing any of those messages falling into there. The saga still exists in Raven, so it is not being deleted. I am just uncertain if maybe it it is a timing issue? Perhaps creating the saga data entity and then sending the next message is happening faster than it is storing the saga data to raven, so the message is not being retrieved? In that case, wouldn't I get a SagaNotFound error message?